# How to restrict access to files to group members?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I have a chat app where users can send photos in private or group chats. Each private or group chat has a unique chat id: `/images/<chat id>/image.jpg`

How would one secure the access to this files so that only the chat members can view them? In the `Firebase database` I have a node with a structure like: `/members/<chat id>/member1: true`.

Is this actually necessary, since the links are only posted to the corressponding chats? 
Can any authed user actually browse through the files saved in the `Firebase storage`? Or is this prevented by design?

Answer (score 3):

The eternal question. It's discussed a few places ([Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/77i9CRlwg88/4iN6jNBLBQAJ;context-place=forum/firebase-talk), [Storage Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security), [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/405c9bf6a1a48a8c17a61b6ff387eaae)), but the TL;DR is: at present, there's no way to read data from one service in the Rules of another. For services, you can do one of two things:

- Convey group information in a custom token
- Convey group information in custom metadata in the service

One example of this:

```
// Allow reads if the group ID in your token matches the file metadata's `owner` property
// Allow writes if the group ID is in the user's custom token
match /files/{groupId}/{fileName} {
  allow read: if resource.metadata.owner == request.auth.token.groupId;
  allow write: if request.auth.token.groupId == groupId;
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you do if a user is allowed to belong to multiple groups?

Comment: Then I usually recommend a solution like in the linked Gist where the ownership information is added to each file vs the user token.

Comment: Linked gist file is not available anymore unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can now access the Firebase Firestore database from your Firebase Storage secturity rules as announced here. https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules

Comment: This is not a valid answer. A link can become invalid over time. Besides that, you should provide an answer, that delivers a solution within the answer itself and add links for reference (if needed). Consider to edit your answer in this regard.