# How to permit a user to edit a file in firebase storage based on data from realtime-database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have firebase storage files stored as following:
PROJECT/location-images/{image}

I also have data in firebase realtime-database stored as following:
PROJECT/users/{UID}/image (value is a string)

The question is.. Can I use firebase storage rules to find the user with a corresponding image and only then allow him to "delete" it.

One possible solution that I know of is to use customMetadata, but customMetadata can not be added directly to existing images. That means I would have to use my app to add every single image in storage one by one.

Comment: There is no connection between the security rules of Cloud Storage for Firebase and the data in the Firebase Realtime Database. You will need to include all the information that is necessary either in the rules directly, or in the security token of the user making the request.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between the security rules of Cloud Storage for Firebase and the data in the Firebase Realtime Database. You will need to include all the information that is necessary either in the rules directly, or in the security token of the user making the request.

Also see:

- [How to restrict access to files to group members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086446/how-to-restrict-access-to-files-to-group-members/41129647#41129647)
- [is there a way to authenticate user role in firebase storage rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187424/is-there-a-way-to-authenticate-user-role-in-firebase-storage-rules)
- [Create group access to firebase storage without using custom authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188459/create-group-access-to-firebase-storage-without-using-custom-authorization)